# Javascript ES6 - is it possible to use/call super class properties or functions without using this keyword in child class

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, object, ecmascript-6

**Javascript ES6 - is it possible to use/call super class properties or functions without using this keyword in child class**

```js
class Parent {

    constructor() {
        this.strings = 'some string values'
        this.utils = 'some util functions'
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super()

    }

    login() {
        //currently i am using like this to access parent class property or functions
        console.log(this.strings.success)

        //but i would like to use like this 
        console.log(strings.success)


    }
}
```

Comment: Not really, you need `this` to reference the instance (though I guess you could pass the instance when you call the method, but that's repetitive) - this seems very strange to want to do. Do you have a reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: it feels very wordy to use this in every child class

Comment: It feels very wordy to write 4 letters... No, this is not Java and there is not implicit `this`.

Comment: yes, i am from Java background that's why i feel wordy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure `this`, and assign the properties to their own variables/constants:

```js
class Parent {

  constructor() {
    this.strings = { success: 'some string values' }
    this.utils = 'some util functions'
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  login() {
    const { strings } = this;

    console.log(strings.success)
  }
}

const child = new Child

child.login()
```

Comment: is it possible to make destructing more dynamic without using destructing parent class properties

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please add an example.

Comment: i want to access parent class properties or functions like in java

Comment: Nope. You'll need to explicitly destructure inside a function.

Comment: This pattern is very typical in react for dealing with `props` and `state` for example.